# Angular 6 : Reloading window (Refresh F5 ) needs an extra "/" in IE11 to reload the current path

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx, angular-ui-router, internet-explorer-11

Un my **Angular 5** app , i have some treatment within my authentication cycle which is handled with nginx .

Nginx adds to my url this suffix : `/root`

When **refreshing** the window (chrome , firefox .. ) that works fine as i'm forcing that route (`/root`) to load a **homePage** component.

***here is my scanrio :***

**t0 :** `http://myUrl`

**t1 :** `http://myUrl/root`  **(added by ngninx)**

**t2 OK :** refresh (firefox Or Chrome)
**->** `http://myUrl/root`

**->** this recalls the nginx and reload successfully the current path (homePage)

**t2 KO :** refresh (**IE11**)

**->** `http://myUrl/root`

**->** this **doesn't recall ngninx** and try to reload directly the component under the `/root` route

***Temporarly solution :*** Only in ***IE11*** : adding " `/` " for the path 
http://myUrl/root/  to get it recalling nginx and reloading successfully the component

To note in my **index.html** :

```
<base href="./">
```

**Any suggesstions to that IE11 behaviour ??**

Comment: Whats in your Nginx conf?